# error LNK1104: cannnot open file 'aocl_utils.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencl, nvidia

I'm trying to run a host code of OpenCL in visual studio and when I compile my code, I get this error

**error LNK1104: cannot open file 'aocl_utils.lib'**

I added aocl_utils.h to my project directories but lib file is unrecognized yet. I would be appreciated to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the linker cannot find the file aocl_utils.lib. If that is the case, just add its name to 'Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional depedendencies' and copy the file to the working directory. Instead of copying the file, you can also paste the library directory to 'Project->Properties->Linker->General->Additional library directories'.

Let me know if my solution solved the problem.

Comment: The folder doesn't contain aocl_utils.lib. In other word, this file doesn't exist on internet even. how could I find it?
The folder which I addressed in directories is obtained from the bottom link
[link](https://github.com/jck/aocl)
and in this link there is not my required file